# Change existing field from Odoo base module (mrp) with computed field or onchange

Tags: python, xml, odoo, backend

Wanting to create a manufacturing order of a product, I want to let the users the choice of selecting the quantity to make in two ways.

On the first hand, they normally introduce the quantity in the existing "product_qty" field, those values referring to the main Unit of measure, per example units.

On the other hand, I also want to let them fill the quantity in another field, those values referring to a secondary Unit of measure, per example boxes, and then get that quantity converted to units and filled in the "product_qty" field. The thing is that depending on the product the units/box change.

For this I made a new field inside product model, and added a related field to that on my mrp.production model... all of this I got it right.

Now the problem is when I want to override the "product_qty" field with an onchange or computed value (preferably computed). I don't know how to apply the computed function to that field without overriding it in my module. i don't want to override it because other functionalities will probably break. I don't know if there is a way to just "extend" the field.

Also, when I try to update it with an onchange it does weird things, like going instantly to "To finish" state just after selecting the product, and even then the field does not get updated.

If I try to do it the other way (convert units to boxes) it works fine, so I'm a little lost with it.

```
from odoo import fields, models, api

classMrpProduction(models.Model):    
    ​_inherit='mrp.production'
    
    ​unidades= fields.Integer(string='Unidades', 
    ​compute='_compute_unidades', readonly=False) #Field to insert "Boxes"    
    ​pastones_por_unidad= fields.Integer(string='Pastones por Unidad', related='product_id.pastones_por_unidad', readonly=True) #Related "Units/Box" field

        ​# This works, to change the number of boxes based on the produc_qty introduced    
    ​@api.depends('product_qty', 'pastones_por_unidad')    
    ​def_compute_unidades(self):        
    ​forproductioninself:            
    ​   ​ifproduction.pastones_por_unidad !=0:                
    ​   ​   ​production.unidades =production.product_qty //production.pastones_por_unidad            
    ​   ​else:                
    ​   ​   ​production.unidades =0

        ​# The other way around doesn't, trying to write directly on "product_qty"    
    ​@api.onchange('unidades')    
    ​def_onchange_product_qty(self):        
    ​self.product_qty=self.unidades*self.pastones_por_unidad
```

I pasted the code of what I have been trying so far, and what has and hasn't worked

Comment: Could you add which Odoo version you're working with? Could help, because Odoo changes code once a while so much, that a solution works for one but not for another version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel that you'd like to look more closely to all the existing `product_qty`, `product_uom` and `product_uom_qty`fields.

On the `product.product` object you have:

- `production.product_id.uom_id` - the base unit of measure (UoM) of the product

On the production order (mrp.production):

- `production.product_qty` - the quantity to produce (in the UoM of the product)
- `production.product_uom_id` - the unit of measure (UoM) of the production order
- `production.product_qty` - the quantity to produce in the UoM of the production order

That allows you to have the product_qty in pieces and the product_uom_qty in box_with_24_pieces for exemple. Odoo should do all the math necessary to compute the quantities.

So I believe that the functionality you want to develop already exists.
Pay attention to the fact that UoM and quantity is also set in the bill of materials (BoM) if there is such.

If for any reason you prefer to stick to your fields `unidades` and `pastones_por_unidad` then you have to implement a _compute method for the product_qty field. What you say about not wanting to overload the _compute method of this field is contradictory because what you want to achieve is exactly to change the value of this field. By the way, I don't think this field is defined as computed in the Production module so you will override nothing.

Your code is not working because you are introducing something like cyclic dependency:

- in the `​@api.onchange('unidades')` method you change the value of product_qty
- because of the `​@api.depends('product_qty',...` you change the value of unidades

I propose you to try to define compute="..." and inverse="..." on the product_qty field and remove the @onchange stuff. Something like this should work:

```
class MrpProduction(models.Model):    
    ​_inherit='mrp.production'
    
    ​unidades = fields.Integer() # number of boxe
    ​pastones_por_unidad = fields.Integer() # Units per box
    product_qty = field.Integer(compute=_compute_product_qty, inverse="_inverse_product_qty")

    ​@api.depends('unidads', 'pastones_por_unidad')    
    ​def_compute_product_qty(self):        
    ​for production in self:            
    ​   ​   ​production.product_qty = production.unidads * production.pastones_por_unidads

    ​def _inverse_product_qty(self):        
    ​    for production in self:            
    ​        ​if production.pastones_por_unidad != 0:                
    ​   ​   ​      production.unidades = production.product_qty // production.pastones_por_unidad            
    ​        ​else:                
    ​   ​   ​      production.unidades = 0
```

Disclaimer: The code is not tested at all :)

Not to say that your variable names must be in English :)

Comment: You are totally right, there wasn't any compute field to override inside product_qty, the error was probably because using the compute method and onchange method at the same time.

Your code solved the issue perfectly. Thank you very much :)

And yes, I will have in mind the language for the next time I need some help.